# I receive method options and return undefined

Tags: json, angularjs, http, authentication, put

I'm writing my login form which provides for a put request to the server.

The communication protocol is JSON

I have to send username and password hashes, using CryptoJS with SHA-256 hash algorithm.

Authentication data must be stored encrypted in the browser as a cookie, and each request is sent to the server as the basis for authentication, when you close the browser window, the data must be deleted.

example put request:

```
PUT my api adress

{"loginRequest": {
"username": "admin",
"hash": "8c6976e5b5410415bde908bd4dee15dfb167a9c873fc4bb8a81f6f2ab448a918"
```

}}

Response OK
Code: 200

```
{"loginResponse": {
"username": "admin",
"name": "Example Admin",
"roles": [
    "USER", "ADMIN"
],
"lastLogin": "2014-02-17+01:00",
"backendVersion": "katconnect-backend-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT"
```

}}

Response Data Validation Error (URI username <> JSON username)
Code: 400

```
{"error": {
"code": "400",
"message": "the message of the error"
```

}}

Response Authentication Error (username or hash is null, user not found, wrong hash value)
Code: 401

```
{"error": {
"code": "401",
"message": "Username or password false"
```

}}

Here is my code:

```
angular.module('validationApp')

.controller('loginCtrl',function ($scope,$http,Base64,$cookieStore) {

$scope.login = function () {
        var user = {
            username: $scope.username,
            hash: CryptoJS.SHA256($scope.password)
        };
        var loginRequest = JSON.stringify(user);
        var credentials = Base64.encode($scope.username + ':' + $scope.password);

     $http({
            method: 'PUT',
            url: url+'/users/'+ $scope.username +'/login',
            data: loginRequest,
            headers:{'Content-Type': 'application/json'}
            })


                .success(function (){
                    $http.defaults.headers.common['Authorization'] = 'Basic ' + credentials;
                    $cookieStore.put( authCookieKey ,credentials);
                })
                .error(function(code){
                if (401 === code) {
                    $scope.invalidUsernamePassword = true;
                    }
                })


    };
```

})

Answer (score 0):

You are doing a cross domain request to the API server. The browser first sends a options request to see if the HTTP method is allowed. Have you setup up CORS middleware from your server? If yes check if the method PUT is in whitlist.

http://better-inter.net/enabling-cors-in-angular-js/